# Identifying SimpleModal html content in an open modal dialog

Tags: jquery, simplemodal

I have a situation where I want to close a particular modal dialog, but not close other modal dialogs. Is there some way to access the html that the modal dialog was formed with. Eg: the modal dialog I want to close was formed by

```
$("div#DivReleaseNotification").modal({
        containerCss: {
            backgroundColor: "Orange",
            borderColor: "Blue",
            font: "bold 16px Arial, Sans-Serif",
            width: 700
        }
    });
```

I only want to close this dialog box. Is there any way to identify a dialog that has been opened. In this case see if the opened dialog has id `DivReleaseNotification`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on from where you want to close the dialog.

You can insert a close element inside the dialog a set the class `simplemodal-close` on it, or you can take a reference of the opened dialog an close it programmatically using `close` method.

Code:

```
var diagToClose;

$('#basic-modal').click(function (e) {
    diagToClose=$("div#DivReleaseNotification").modal({
        containerCss: {
            backgroundColor: "Orange",
            borderColor: "Blue",
            font: "bold 16px Arial, Sans-Serif",
            width: 700
        }
    });

    return false;
});

$('#basic-closer').click(function (e) {
    diagToClose.close();
    return false;
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/Sv64m/